# MULalpha and DIValpha operations in SNOW 3G

Tags: stream-cipher, finite-field, lfsr

I'm not able to appreciate the importance of mul alpha and div alpha operations in feedback polynomial of LFSR in SNOW 3G. What problems or weakness do they help in mitigating and how ?

Comment: Make the feedback shift register non-linear? It is no more LFSR!

Comment: @kelalaka : How is multiplication with a fixed element non linear, I mean we can still write output as a linear combination Pi*Xi (Pi is fixed for each tap point - i), can't we ?